# Why do queries with a slash work, but no trailing slash get 404's in my Nginx config?

Tags: nginx

Against below nginx config:

```
upstream search {
          least_conn;
          server www.google.com:80
              max_fails=1
              fail_timeout=10
              weight=1;
            keepalive 12;
        }
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=search:1m rate=10r/s;

resolver 127.0.0.1;

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  charset utf-8;
  server_name _;

  access_log /dev/stdout json;

    location @search {
      # Deny requests that do not match allowed methods REGEX
      if ($request_method !~ ^GET$ ) {
        return 405;
      }
      set $proxy_uri $uri;
      if ($proxy_uri ~ ^/[^/]+(/.*)$ ) {
        set $proxy_uri "$1";
      }
      # Deny requests that do not match allowed paths REGEX
      if ($proxy_uri !~ ^.*(\?|$) ) {
        return 403;
      }

      # Rate Limit Requests
      limit_req zone=search burst=10 nodelay;

      # Adding new client_max_body_size service attribute per location
      client_max_body_size 1m;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      # Set CORS Headers
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
      proxy_set_header Origin "";
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://search$proxy_uri$is_args$args;
      }

    location /search/ {
      client_max_body_size 1m;
      # send request to the named location for the service
      error_page 418 = @search; return 418;
    }
  # Default location for unmatched requests
  location / {
      return 404;
    }

  location = /health {
    return 200;
  }
}
```

Running

```
curl -siL  -H 'Host: www.google.com' '127.0.0.1/search/'
```

returns a 200

but

```
curl -siL  -H 'Host: www.google.com' '127.0.0.1/search'
```

Returns a 404.

How do I make with and with out the slash return 200?

Comment: The title is contradictory, "no slash" and "no trailing slash" sound the same. You mean "with slash works" and "no trailing slash" doesn't?

Comment: True, I made this at the EOD and was not thinking straight. Thanks

Comment: You may want to try changing `location /search/` to `location /search`. Otherwise, you might wish to look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645853/add-slash-to-the-end-of-every-url-need-rewrite-rule-for-nginx) about adding a trailing slash with regex.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar experience, though on a different environment, so you may need to test it yourself to verify. On Apache, for example, if you configure to allow `CORS`(cross origin resource sharing), it appears to only work when there is a trailing slash. The only explanation I could come up with for this was that the server needs to be able to explicitly tell between directories and files (after all, a file can have no extension and end up looking like a directory, and so can a directory name have a dot and end up looking like a file) in order to  allow or disallow `CORS`, and, consequently, almost every query you run on your server. Do your testing and verify if this is true in your case.